# lighttpd.conf - document root as directory containing config file

Tags: lighttpd

I want to use lighttpd as a development server, similar to WEBrick for Rails, or `manage.py runserver` for Django. (This is for both PHP and for learning Javascript where I can't use AJAX on the local filesystem). I also want to be able to share the result with other developers through checking in the conf file to source control along with the code, so I want paths relative to the conf file, not absolute paths that are only valid on my system.

So I saw [this answer about using lighttpd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5438057/3189) which is very close to what I want. However, rather than having to change to the correct directory and then run the script, ideally I want to be able to do:

```
lighttpd -f path/to/lighttpd.conf
```

and for the document root to be relative to the directory the lighttpd.conf file is in. So I want to be able to have a config line something like:

```
server.document-root = dirname(__file__) + "/html"
```

The answer linked to above uses `CWD` for the directory, so this seems like something that might well be available. Any idea how to specify it?

*(As a side note, can anyone link to a comprehensive reference to `lighttpd.conf` and the options available? I haven't been able to find one.)*

Comment: About the configuration, every thing is on the [official documentation](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs:ConfigurationOptions). I didn't find anything better atm.

Answer (score 3):

That is not possible - you should (as you already know)

```
cd /some/testing/dir/with/your/stuff
lighttpd -f lighttpd.conf
```

plus the `var.CWD` in your directory

```
server.document-root = var.CWD
```

An alternative would be to patch lighttpd yourself with an option that supplies an additional pseudo-chroot argument.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `envsubst` on your config, setting up `$PWD` or some other variable

`envsubst < lighttpd.conf.template > lighttpd.conf`